# How do I access a table within a schema without having to use the schema prefix (Postgres + PHP)?

Tags: php, postgresql

I have some tables created under a schema. At the moment, I can access the table within the schema using:

```
select * from myschema.mytable
```

I am searching for ways to avoid using the schema name. something like:

```
select * from mytable
```

But I'm not finding the answers.

Can you help? Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why do you want to avoid schema name?

Comment: You can use SET search path; as in SET search_path TO myschema, public; this affects the whole session

Answer (score 17):

Schema search path would work for this:

To see the current value:

```
SHOW search_path;
```

To change the value (append new schema):

```
SET search_path TO myschema,public;
```

It is documented [here, in section 5.7.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-schemas.html)

Comment: apologies but I wasn't very clear. how do I do this from within PHP?

Comment: @mrjayviper just run the `SET` statement under PHP (before your other queries). Note that the schema you want to access is not necessarily the first -- the first schema in the search path only controls where to create new tables (and the access order, if you have multiple tables with same name in separate schemas)