# How do I add tables to a specific schema in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema

I have this:

```
DROP SCHEMA Lab1 CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA Lab1;
CREATE TABLE Lab1.PERSONS(
SSN   INT primary key,
Name CHARACTER (30),
HouseId  INT,
ApartmentNumber  INT ,
Salary   DECIMAL (5, 2)  
);
```

But this doesn't work, it creates the schema fine but then creates the table in a weird place where it can't be viewed (with `\d+` for example), in fact, the only way I know it exists is if you try to drop the "lab1" schema it will throw an error saying that schema is being used by lab1.

I tried setting the default path to the lab1 schema: `ALTER ROLE -myusername- SET SEARCH_PATH to Lab1;`

But that didn't work either, `\d+` still has "persons" in public.

So, how do I get this table into the schema I want? Thanks.

Comment: did you run `\d+ "Lab1".PERSONS` in psql or `\d+ Lab1.PERSONS`?..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

tried runnig:

```
DROP SCHEMA Lab1 CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA Lab1;
CREATE TABLE Lab1.PERSONS(
SSN   INT primary key,
Name CHARACTER (30),
HouseId  INT,
ApartmentNumber  INT ,
Salary   DECIMAL (5, 2)  
);
t=# \dt+ lab1.persons
 lab1   | persons | table | postgres | 0 bytes |
```

As you can see the table is created in lab1 schema. If you want it in `Lab1` schema, you should modify your statemet:

```
t=#     DROP SCHEMA "Lab1" CASCADE;
ERROR:  schema "Lab1" does not exist
t=#     CREATE SCHEMA "Lab1";
CREATE SCHEMA
t=#     CREATE TABLE "Lab1".PERSONS(
t(#     SSN   INT primary key,
t(#     Name CHARACTER (30),
t(#     HouseId  INT,
t(#     ApartmentNumber  INT ,
t(#     Salary   DECIMAL (5, 2)
t(#     );
CREATE TABLE
t=#     \dt+ "Lab1".persons
 Lab1   | persons | table | postgres | 0 bytes |
```

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in a response, I get the same thing you do. Is there any command to see all relations in all schemas? Because it seems like doing \dt+ just gets the public schema. Thanks.

Comment: `select * from pg_tables` will do. And if there is a meta-command in psql?.. not sure. You can list schemas with `\dn` and then tables

Comment: I doubt there is -  I suppose psql users `search_path` for list of schemas

Comment: What helped me most is the hint of enclosing schema name with double quotes e.g. `"Lab1"`, I even tried using a schema that includes dots e.g. `"v0.1"` and this also works fine, and I could use it directly inside Query Tool window

Answer (score 0):

You can run this before creating the table creation. That way don't have to add schema prefix

```
SET search_path TO myschema;
```

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26726006)