# postgresql nextval throws error relation does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following sql:

```
 INSERT INTO in_api_settings ( 
   ENTITY_ID, 
   ACTIVE_START_DATE, 
   ACTIVE_END_DATE) 
 VALUES ( 
   nextval('in_api_settings_seq'), 
   current_date, 
   null)
```

And when i execute it i get error

> ERROR:  relation "in_api_settings_seq" does not exist

On Oracle i use IN_API_SETTINGS_SEQ.NEXTVAL and this works fine. I am merging from Oracle to PostgreSQL and not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @VaoTsun yes i created it with pgAdmin4 and i can see it in Sequences, they are under same schema table and sequence

Comment: @VaoTsun yes this worked, it is the same user tho is there a way to check this

Comment: @VaoTsun latest 10

Comment: In PostgreSQL, the "current" schemas are defined by `search_path` and have nothing to do with the user that owns the table or the session user (unless there is `"$user"` in your `search_path`).

Comment: `select relnamespace::regnamespace,relowner::regrole from pg_class where relname = 'in_api_settings_seq' and relkind = 'S';`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I always had `"$user"` as first listed - and frankly saying thought it was default?..

Comment: @VaoTsun it returns same username  - test  - test -

Comment: @MasterYi and what's in `select current_setting('search_path');`?..

Comment: @VaoTsun '"$user", public'

Comment: then I don't see any obvious reason why it does not find the sequence - if you are user test. maybe @LaurenzAlbe will know

Comment: @VaoTsun it is ok i don't know either if i find the reason i will inform you, thank you for support

Answer (score 17, accepted):

specify schema in

```
nextval('in_api_settings_seq')
```

so it would be

```
nextval('schema_name.in_api_settings_seq')
```

also from the sequence naming I believe it was auto generated, thus it would be assigned as default value to, and thus you could try

```
INSERT INTO in_api_settings ( 
   ENTITY_ID, 
   ACTIVE_START_DATE, 
   ACTIVE_END_DATE) 
 VALUES ( 
   DEFAULT, 
   current_date, 
   null)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer i will try your suggestion to use with DEFAULT

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725816/how-do-i-access-a-table-within-a-schema-without-having-to-use-the-schema-prefix this fixed the need to use schema_name in front of the sequence

Comment: It's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 15):

Use separate quotes for schema and sequence

```
SELECT NEXTVAL('"schema_name"."sequence_tbl"')
```

Eg. `SELECT NEXTVAL('"Master_SHM"."ATTRIBUTE_ID_SEQ"');`

```
 nextval
---------
       5
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

in my particular case, it has worked by using simple quotes and separating schema name with double quotes" dot (.) double quotes with sequenece name:

Solution:

[image]