# Access a postgres table using the schema prefix in c#

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, search-path

I'm using postgres in a c# project and i'm trying to make some basic queries such as

```
qry.CommandText = "select * from LOGIN";
NpgsqlDataReader qryReader = qry.ExecuteReader();
```

But it says that the table LOGIN does not exist.

I already know that the following query works: `qry.CommandText = "select * from \"myDataBase\".LOGIN";`  but I would prefer not using it.

I also know from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725816/how-do-i-access-a-table-within-a-schema-without-having-to-use-the-schema-prefix) that I can use `SET search_path TO myschema,public;` to access the table without prefix in psql command line, but I don't see how it would work for my c# projet.

Also, I have another project where I don't need the prefix but I don't know why it works for my other projet and not this one.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `SET search_path TO myschema,public;` sets the [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) for the current session only, you can make it permanent for the user running the command:

`ALTER USER username SET search_path TO myschema, public;`

Comment: I accept this answer as this solves the problem but would there be a solution when you have several schemas per user ? Or is this bad practice?

Comment: You can add multiple schemas (`ALTER USER username SET search_path TO myschema,myschema2,myschema3, public;`). If you want to do this for all users, you can set the search path at the database level (`alter database mydb set search_path = "$user", myschema, public ;`)